# PDE solver that handles constraints

Tags: python, math, numerical-methods, solver, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a system of partial differential equations of the general form

```
F(f(x,y), f'(x,y), f''(x,y), g(x,y), g'(x,y), g''(x,y)) = 0
```

where the derivatives may be taken with respect to both x and y and `f(x,y)` and `g(x,y)` are subject to some constraint

```
G(f(x,y),g(x,y)) = 0
```

I wonder if there exists any (preferably Python based) solver (not a method, as I know the methods) that can deal with a problem of this kind? Would appreciate any help and apologise if my question seems to general.

Answer (score 0):

Such a problem will require initial conditions and boundary conditions to be satisfied to obtain an unique solution. Also you will need to provide a domain (geometry) to the solver. I think you must look at finite element solvers in python.

Just a quick Google search provided few finite element solvers in python, however I have not tested any. So I guess that would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a finite element solver, [Fenics](http://fenicsproject.org/) has python bindings.